# Get default url from this json?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

```
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("message");
            for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                arrayList.add(new Product(
                       productObject.getString("url"),
                        productObject.getString("title"),
                        productObject.getString("description")
                ));
```

---

```
    {  
   "message":[  
      {  
         "id":"hT_nvWreIhg",
         "link":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hT_nvWreIhg",
         "kind":"youtube#video",
         "publishedAt":"2013-05-31T07:00:36.000Z",
         "channelId":"UCQ5kHOKpF3-1_UCKaqXARRg",
         "channelTitle":"OneRepublicVEVO",
         "title":"OneRepublic - Counting Stars",
         "description":"Get OneRepublic's new album 'Oh My My,' featuring 'Kids,' 'Wherever I Go' and 'Let's Hurt Tonight:' http://smarturl.it/OhMyMy Listen to the Best of OneRepublic ...",
         "thumbnails":{  
            "default":{  
               "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hT_nvWreIhg/default.jpg",
               "width":120,
               "height":90
            },
            "medium":{  
               "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hT_nvWreIhg/mqdefault.jpg",
               "width":320,
               "height":180
            },
            "high":{  
               "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hT_nvWreIhg/hqdefault.jpg",
               "width":480,
               "height":360
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `productObject.getString("url")` to return anything? That's not saying **which** url you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two more calls to `getJSONObject`:

```
JSONObject defaultObject = productObject.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("default")
```

and then use

```
arrayList.add(new Product(
    defaultObject.getString("url"),
    productObject.getString("title"),
    productObject.getString("description")
));
```

Comment: thinks man, but it dosen't work , I just have a problem to get the url to show image in listView , the title and description are ok

Comment: @youssefhrizi cricket_007 fixed an error in the answer, try again please.

Comment: it work , think you very much